# How to select last id(where id >0) fod each group in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I want to select last record of price column of my table where my value of column is greater than zero. How can I do that?

My stored procedure is :

```
SELECT 
    id, name, price
FROM 
    messages
WHERE 
    id IN (SELECT MAX(id)
           FROM messages
           WHERE price > 0
           GROUP BY name)
```

The problem is that this code select max id that price is greater than zero not last id. Means select id=2 and id=6

But in last id of group (frank) price is zero but this stored procedure select id=2 while I want stored procedure select only id =6

```
id name price
--------------
1 frank 1000
2 frank  500
3 frank    0
4 john   200
5 john   100
6 john    20
```

Comment: `TOP 1` when `ORDER BY id DESC`?

Comment: Can you please share the table's structure, some sample data and the result you're trying to get? It's a bit hard to address the question as it's currently phrase.

Comment: You mention "last" twice in your post. Define last. By definition a database table is an unordered set and there is no concept of last. You need to define what last means in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to approach this.  Following your method, though, you just need to move the price comparison to the outer query:

```
SELECT id, name, price
FROM messages
WHERE price > 0 AND
      id IN (SELECT MAX(id)
             FROM messages
             GROUP BY name
            );
```

I would be more inclined to write this as:

```
select m.*
from (select m.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by id desc) as seqnum
      from messages m
     ) m
where seqnum = 1 and price > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as (
select row_number() over(partition by id order by id desc) rn,
id,name,price
from messages
)
select id,name,price
from cte
where rn=1 and price>0
```

Something like this.